# Grafana: Returns just a white page

Tags: javascript, grafana

I am successfully running Grafan on my Raspberry Pi 3 for some time now. But till today I suddenly only get a white page when I open the Grafana Webpage in my Browser(Firefox).

The docs of Grafana says that this may be a error in config.js. [Link](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/troubleshooting/)

This is my config.js But I never changed something here or updated in the last weeks:

```
define(["app/core/settings"],function(a){"use strict";var b=window.grafanaBootData||{settings:{}},c=b.settings;return new a(c)});
```

With the developertool i see that I have a **SyntaxError: illegal character** in this line:

```
var requirejs,require,define;!function(clobal){function i³Dujction(a){return"[bject unction]"===oStzing.call(a)}function i3Array(a){reTurn"[object Array]"===o3tring.ca,l(a)|fenction each(a,b){if(a){var c{for(c=0;c<a.length&&(!a{c]|
```

I have no Idea whats my problem here since I didn´t changed anything on my installation.

Comment: I would start by checking your storage (I assume an SD card), it may be flipping bits.

Comment: @robertklep thank you for your help, but how can I check for that ?

Comment: Try what's being suggested in [this answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/3296) (although an `fsck` alone may not necessarily catch all filesystem problems).

Comment: @robertklep You are right I tracked to problem down to the file "app.ca0ab6f9.js" in the first line there are some wrong chars. I think the easiest way is to replace that file with the original one. But I have the feeling its some kind of auto generated since I can´t find it in the github.

Comment: There is a reason why the file suddenly became incorrect, and my guess is that your SD card may be failing.